# Using Google translation through my application

Tags: c#, .net, google-translate

I have two text boxes and button in my application, one for the main text and the other for the translated text.

I am trying to do this task by Google translation API, the problem that I have to sign up my website, I am still developing and running my application on my laptop.

What can I do with the API key? How can I get it without having a website?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can pass the credentidals as arguments to the api. Just check the API documents.

Comment: Just a heads up, but the translate api will not work after December 1, 2011. Meaning you're application won't work after that date. http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

Answer (score 3):

**Important:** The Google Translate API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. Due to the substantial economic burden caused by extensive abuse, the number of requests you may make per day will be limited and the API will be **shut off completely on December 1, 2011.** For website translations, we encourage you to use the Google Translate Element.

As Google suggests perhaps it would be simpler than creating your own to use one thats already made:

Here: http://www.google.com/webelements/#!/translate

```
<!-- Google Translate Element -->
<div id="google_translate_element" style="display:block"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: "af"}, "google_translate_element");
};</script>
<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

or here: http://babelfish.yahoo.com/free_trans_service

Comment: new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: "af"}
when I use this code, it gives me an error that google  is not recognised

Comment: @Faha, sorry.. I've updated my answer to contain all the HTML required for using the Google Web Element Translation.

Answer (score 0):

Google says:

> We highly encourage you to include an API key with each request. While
>   a key is not required, using one allows us to identify and contact you
>   to correct any problems. Read more about [why it's useful to have an
>   API key](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/signup.html).

Seems you don't need one.